# How to make Native Web View disappear?

Tags: distriqt

Basically, I need to set a visible property, or just call a hide() method to make it invisible in the screen, is there any way to do that?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently isn't possible. You have two options, either make the view very small (1x1 px) or remove and recreate the view.

This feature is on our list of enhancements on github, feel free to add a comment there if you have any requirements.

Cheers

Comment: I could make it disappear by moving it out of stage, didn't notice any issues with that so far, if it can cause a problem please let me know.